# Reduce colums in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of sparse matrix and I want to reorder them. An example of a little matrix sparse could be:

```
x = [[0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 2, 3],
     [4, 0, 0, 5],
     [0, 0, 6, 0]]
```

Then, the reduced output that I am looking for, is:

```
y = [[1, 0],
     [2, 3],
     [4, 5],
     [6, 0]]
```

Because the maximun number of not nulls elements in all rows is 2, then the maximun number of columns also is 2 and is necessary fill the row with zeros at the end.

One way to implement it, is convert the matrix in a list of lists, in each sub-list remove the zero elements and insert zeros at the end to maintain the size consistency between rows, and finally convert anew in a numpy array but I think this is inefficient. Is there anyway to achieve it using numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the max number of non-zero elements in a row, and then find values with rank above that number (based on your example I'm assuming non-zero values are positive; if there are negative values as well, then we can add `abs` before taking the rank):

```
# get the max number of non-zero elements in a row (2 in our example)
n = (x!=0).sum(0).max()

# get values with rank equal to or above `n`
x[x.argsort().argsort()>=n].reshape(-1, n)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a zero np array of size rows_of_x X max_non_zero_per_row
a = np.zeros((len(x), np.sum(x != 0, axis=1).max()))
# iterate over each row and get the non zero element
for i in range(len(a)):
    v = x[i][x[i] != 0]
    a[i][:len(v)] = v

print (a)
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [2., 3.],
       [4., 5.],
       [6., 0.]])
```